# Pictures of people breaking the law in Facebook

Tags: civil-law, photography, covid-19, portugal, civil-rights

Within this COVID19 pandemic various activities were forbidden in Portugal, like spearfishing or catching crabs in rocks. Yet, some people insist on doing them (let's call them rebels) but in a "hidden" way. For instances, instead of catching crabs with the proper tools, they go with a dog nearby as if they're walking the dog (walking the dog is allowed).

Considering this real life case, some people (spies) try to "make justice" by taking photos of rebels when they are performing the forbidden activities, without permission, and then they go to social media, like Facebook, and expose it.

I'm not trying to justify the behaviour of the rebels. Can't stop but to wonder how legal is it what the spies are doing? If not legal, how should a rebel proceed of was damaged by such thing?

Comment: The Portuguese Civil Code has an article on the ["Direito à imagem"](https://dre.pt/legislacao-consolidada/-/lc/106487514/201703171158/73407134/diploma/indice).